# Select boxes auto populated by JSON sometimes need a refresh before displaying

Tags: php, javascript, html, json, select

I have a JSON file that is being used to autopopulate some select boxes.  Every now and then (I can't recreate the fault, it appears to be random) the items in the drop down do not display until I refresh the page.

I've checked the console and log etc, the file is loading fine, no errors are appearing and I'm a little at a loss.

Any ideas?

Example of JSON and the script that reads it below.

Thanks.

```
"radAbsorbed" : [
    {
        "value" : "rad",
        "name" : "Rad(rd)"
    },
    {
        "value" : "millirad",
        "name" : "Millirad(mrd)"
    }]
```

and the script:

```
<script>
//        JSON:
//        The key is the class identifier, temp, area etc etc
//        Value is being used for both ID and Value when the list is being populated
    $.getJSON('JSON/conversionJSON.json', function(data){

        console.log(data);
        //for testing output only
        var list = $("<ul />");

        $.each(data, function (key, conversions) {
            console.log(key + ":" + conversions);

            $.each(conversions, function (index, conversion) {
                console.log("<li>Name: " + conversion.name + " :Value: " + conversion.value + "</li>");

                if(key == "<?php echo $conversionType ?>"){

                    $("#from").append('<option class="'+key+'" id="'+conversion.value+'" value="'+conversion.value+'">'+conversion.name+'</option>');
                    //testing output
                    var elem = $("<li>Name: " + conversion.name + " :Value: " +     conversion.value + "</li>").appendTo(list);
                }
            });
        });
        //$("#testJSON").html(list);
    });
</script>
```

EDIT:
Updated script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.getJSON('JSON/conversionJSON.json', function(data){

    console.log(data);
    //for testing output only
    var list = $("<ul />");

    $.each(data, function (key, conversions) {
        console.log(key + ":" + conversions);

        $.each(conversions, function (index, conversion) {
            console.log("<li>Name: " + conversion.name + " :Value: " + conversion.value + "</li>");

            if(key == "<?php echo $conversionType ?>"){

                $("#from").append('<option class="'+key+'" id="'+conversion.value+'" value="'+conversion.value+'">'+conversion.name+'</option>');
                $("#to").append('<option class="'+key+'" id="'+conversion.value+'" value="'+conversion.value+'">'+conversion.name+'</option>');
                //testing output
                var elem = $("<li>Name: " + conversion.name + " :Value: " + conversion.value + "</li>").appendTo(list);
            }
        });
    });
    //$("#testJSON").html(list);
});
});
```

EDIT:  Thanks everyone for their help, it seems to be working fine and looked like an amateur mistake on my part.

Comment: Where is this `<script>` tag placed in your HTML? In the `<head>` section?

Comment: Are you running the script in the document ready handler?

Comment: @Travesty3, Hi, yes, it's within the Head tags

Comment: @Barmar, No I don't believe I am, I'm very new to JS.  Literally the script above is included in the head along with some other script src's.

SHould I wrap it in a $(document).ready(function)() ?

Comment: yes you do, have to wrap it inside the `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Comment: @CME64, thanks.  I've done that now.  Think I need to do some more reading but I assume that ensures that the script doesn't run before anything else?

Comment: It ensures that the DOM elements that it references, such as `#from` and `#to`, will be in the browser's memory by the time it runs. Every jQuery tutorial should say that you should run your code like this.

Comment: this runs the script after all the dom elements of your document are loaded so that you can select and manipulate them. but you can't do that before they are loaded.. in js you can use `window.onload = function(){/* code */}` as an alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that your script is sometimes running before the document is ready.

Try wrapping your code in a document ready function:

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON(...)
    // ...
});
```

This will make it so that the code doesn't execute before the elements it's affecting are created. For instance, if your code executes before the element with the ID `from` gets created, then `$('#from')` will not match any elements, and it won't work.

Wrapping it in a document ready function will make sure that your code waits until the elements have been created before executing.

Alternatively, you could move your `<script>` tag out of the head and place it right after the `#from` element in your HTML. This might help it load slightly faster.

Comment: Your updated script looks correct to me. Is it working for you?

Comment: Thank you for the extra explanation.  I'm hoping on getting the JSON stored into a session variable somehow to prevent it from being loaded everytime a new category is selected.